# How do I select the TD of the TH to which it references with only CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I saw JavaScript answers but not using CSS only.  Is it possible, using only CSS, to reference the table cell to which the table head is meant to reference?

If I have:

```
    <table id="required-education">
       <thead>
          <tr>
             <th class="tbl-requirement-subheader" colspan=3>
                Basic Skills (General Core) Courses - Area III
             </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <th class="tbl-area-description" colspan=3>
                Social/Behavioral Sciences

             </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <th class="tbl-class-header">Class Name</th>
             <th class="tbl-class-header">Description</th>
             <th class="tbl-class-header">Hours</th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td> <!-- how do I select these next three td cells only with only CSS? -->
                EMPL 999
             </td>
             <td>Interpersonal Relations and Professional Development</td>
             <td>2</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
             <td class="tbl-class-decription" colspan=3>a description
    2 credits
             </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td colspan=3 class="tbl-prerequisite">Prerequisite</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td class="tbl-prerequisite-info" colspan=3>
                Provisional admission
             </td>
          </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: @SleekGeek for example td of some row and column 1 is selected, th of column 1 should be referenced/selected. Even i got confused a little bit. I hope i got it right OP.

Comment: Richard, read the HTML comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the position of the tr, you can use child selectors. In your example you could use

```
tbody tr:first-child td {
  your styles
}
```

Comment: or even 
    `tbody tr:nth-child(nth_col_no) td{
        style
    }`

Comment: What if I have multiple rows?  This only gets the first one it hits.  I'm using the nth-child(1) which of course only works for 1, but what if I have 10?  Is that when I have to start using JavaScript?

Comment: It got it.  Just use n.

Comment: @johnny: Or just leave out the :nth-child() altogether. Not sure where you are using that pseudo-class, but :nth-child(n) is redundant.